# String.Split Method not working as intended

Tags: c#, split

I'm trying to split this Equation between every operator, but the String.Split Method outputs the the wrong number

Code:

```
string tmpEquation = "200.2−-23.5";
double[] Numbers;
Numbers = tmpEquation.Split(new char[] { '+', '−', '*', '/' })
          .Select(s => Double.Parse(s))
          .ToArray()
;
```

Output:

```
Number[0] = 2002.0
Number[1] = -235.0
```

It should be:

```
Number[0] = 200.2
Number[1] = -23.5
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @HuorSwords Don't do it. A bad way to resolve *locale problems*.

Comment: I don't think you will get second number as -235, since you are splitting on - it will remove the minus sign.

Comment: @Selman22 Those are two different chars, to differentiate a negative number and the operator.

Comment: @L.B agree. I retire it! :)

Comment: yes you're right. I haven't realized that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parsing is culture sensitive. Probably your culture is using a different decimal separator than `dot (.)`. You can use `InvariantCulture` for parsing:

```
Numbers = tmpEquation.Split(new char[] { '+', '−', '*', '/' })
      .Select(s => Double.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
      .ToArray()
```

Comment: Thanks! I always get confused whether its ',' or '.', since we use the ',' as the decimal point in germany.

Comment: @Encore as an aside you can get the decimal separator of your culture using: `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator`